# how to include 2 joins into a union statement

Tags: sql-server, left-join

I want to merge plan and actual data into 1 view using Union.
For this I use two inner joins to make the rows match - then I use a union statement. Currently I do this in 3 steps - now I want to merge all this into 1 step.

Example

**create vPlan2**

```
Select 
   a.step, 
   a.[planned user], 
   b.[actual user], 
   a.[invoice plan] as 'invoice'
from vPlan a
inner join vActuals b on a.step = b.step
group by 
   a.step, 
   a.[planned user], 
   b.[actual user], 
   a.[invoice plan]
```

**create vActuals2**

```
Select 
    a.step, 
    b.[planned user], 
    a.[actual user], 
    a.[invoice actuals] as 'invoice'
from vActuals a
inner join vPlan b on a.step = b.step
group by 
    a.step, 
    a.[actual user], 
    b.[planned user], 
    a.[invoice actuals]
```

**create vplanandactuals**

```
select 
    'Plan' as type, 
    a.step, 
    a.[planned user], 
    a.invoice, 
    a.[actual user]
from vPlan2 a
group by 
    a.step, 
    a.[planned user], 
    a.invoice, 
    a.[actual user]
Union
select 
    'Actuals', 
    b.step, 
    b.[planned user], 
    b.invoice, 
    b.[actual user]
from vActuals2 b
group by 
    b.step, 
    b.[planned user], 
    b.invoice, 
    b.[actual user]
```

Comment: what's up with all the grouping? there is no aggregation. What errors are you getting / problems are you having?

Comment: What is your question? Why the left-join tag? Why is your union inadequate?

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @texastonie's answer, but replacing the `group by` with `select distinct`:

```
Select Distinct
   'Plan' as type, 
   vPlan.step, 
   vPlan.[planned user], 
   vPlan.[invoice plan] as 'invoice',
   vActuals.[actual user] 
from vPlan
inner join vActuals
  on vPlan.step = vActuals.step
union
Select Distinct
    'Actuals' as type, 
    vActuals.step, 
    vPlan.[planned user], 
    vActuals.[invoice actuals] as 'invoice',
    vActuals.[actual user] 
from vActuals
inner join vPlan
  on vActuals.step = vPlan.step
;
```

Comment: Definitely should use distinct instead of group by. I'm wondering if we actually need a distinct at all here.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
Select 
   'Plan' as Type,
   a.step, 
   a.[planned user], 
   b.[actual user], 
   a.[invoice plan] as 'invoice'
from vPlan a
inner join vActuals b on a.step = b.step
group by 
   a.step, 
   a.[planned user], 
   b.[actual user], 
   a.[invoice plan]

union all

Select 
    'Actuals' as Type,
    a.step, 
    b.[planned user], 
    a.[actual user], 
    a.[invoice actuals] as 'invoice'
from vActuals a
inner join vPlan b on a.step = b.step
group by 
    a.step, 
    a.[actual user], 
    b.[planned user], 
    a.[invoice actuals]
```